# Redirect old wordpress site pages to new php site urls using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

1. I had a website 'example.com', which was in wordpress initially but i had to move it to php.
2. Now my site is in php. The problem now is, i tried redirecting urls, for ex:-`http://www.example.com/about-mysite/`, to my new url using Redirect 301 in .htaccess file.
3. Suppose my old page is /about-example/, i redirect it as,

   ```
   Redirect 301 /about-mysite/ http://www.example.com/about-example.php
   ```

but it is not getting redirected.

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On`                                                                                      
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php `
`RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] `

`Redirect 301 /about-kankaria-eye-hospital/ http://www.asianeyehospital.com/about-kankaria-eye-hospital.php`. I hope this is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this redirect rule right at top of your .htaccess **before WP rules**:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(about-kankaria-eye-hospital)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

Suggested **generic redirect rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: If i have number of pages like the above one, then should i use the same  RewriteRule for every page??